# iOS self.navigationController.toolbar position to top doesn't change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change `self.navigationController.toolbar` position to top instead of a bottom.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIToolbarDelegate, UIBarPositioningDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

// View did load
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Superclass view did load method call
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // UIToolbarDelegate
    self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x, 64.0f, self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"First", @"Second"]];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 10.0f, 220.0f, 24.0f);
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];
}

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}

@end
```

The position changes at first, but later gets back to the bottom. Please, help me!

Comment: Check if the positionForBar method gets called. It doesn't look like you set the delegate....

Comment: Yea, kinda. I want to make navigation bar with segmented control. The best way to do that, as far as I know, is to add toolbar below it. I have googled this issue. Other people does that without any problem. I don't know why I can't...

Comment: No. It is not called. Despite of delegate in .h file...

Comment: Application crashes in line `self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;` with error `Cannot manually set the delegate on a UIToolbar managed by a controller`...

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that toolbar delegate method `positionForBar:` is get called. If not, then your toolbar delegate is not properly set and you've have to define the `UIToolbarDelegate` protocol inside your header class.

```
@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController <UIToolbarDelegate>
...

@end
```

Then set the delegate and also change the frames for toolbar. However, for the orientation you might have to reconsider the frames of toolbar.

```
    @implementation ExampleViewController

         - (void)viewDidLoad {

             [super viewDidLoad];

             // set the toolbar delegate
             self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;
             self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

             // create a toolbar child items
             UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"First", @"Second"]];
             segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.with, 24.0f);
             segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
             [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:segmentedControl];

             // set the frames
             CGRect toolbarFrame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
             toolbarFrame.origin.y = self.navigationController.frame.size.height;
             self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
          }

         // pragma mark - UIToolbarDelegate
         - (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
         {
             return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
         }

   @end
```

Comment: Application crashes in line `self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;` with error `Cannot manually set the delegate on a UIToolbar managed by a controller.`. Why?

Answer (score -2):

In your viewDidLoad method, add:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Error: Cannot manually set the delegate on a UIToolbar managed by a controller.